# Is there any way to apply discounts on purchase bill programmatically?

Tags: netsuite

We have the requirement 'apply discounts on purchase bill before taxes' at the line item level.
For that, we have created one Discount field at the line item level. Rate value should be discounted based on the value in the 'Discount' custom field. Amount value will be updated based on quantity and rate.

I have tried with the workflow but it is not working. Can anyone help me in Scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you would be using client scripts, you can use the validateLine function which will be triggered after clicking the Add button on the Item Sublist.

```
function checkDiscount(type){
    var getDiscount = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'internalID of discount field');
    var currRate = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate');
    var newRate = currRate * getDiscount; // depending on the value stored in Discount, you may need to modify this further
    nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'rate'); 

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Validate Line events occur prior to a line item being added to a sublist.